# Vercel throws an 405 Method not allowed on trpc

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, next.js, deployment

### Problem

I have a t3-stack app that uses trpc. Locally it works fine, but when it comes to the app deployed on Vercel it throws an error of 405 Method not allowed.

When I go to the log file on vercel there is a weird error

```
/var/lang/bin/node: Relink `/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/@prisma+client@5.8.1_prisma@5.9.1/node_modules/.prisma/client/libquery_engine-rhel-openssl-1.0.x.so.node' with `/lib64/librt.so.1' for IFUNC symbol `clock_gettime'
/var/lang/bin/node: Relink `/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/@prisma+client@5.8.1_prisma@5.9.1/node_modules/.prisma/client/libquery_engine-rhel-openssl-1.0.x.so.node' with `/lib64/librt.so.1' for IFUNC symbol `clock_gettime'
Error: Runtime exited with error: signal: segmentation fault
Runtime.ExitError
```

### Steps tried

- trpc configured that it accepts ssr https://trpc.io/docs/v10/client/nextjs/ssr
- allowed all origins and every method on vercel.json and next.config

next.config.js

```
  headers: async () => {
    return [
      {
        source: "/api/*",
        headers: [
          {
            key: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
            value: "*",
          },
          {
            key: "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
            value: "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE",
          },
          {
            key: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
            value:
              "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version",
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
  },
```

vercel.json

```
{
  "headers": [
    {
      "source": "/api/*",
      "headers": [
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "value": "true" },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "value": "*" },
        {
          "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
          "value": "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT"
        },
        {
          "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
          "value": "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I appreciate any hints, to solve it with TRPC but if it is not possible, what would be the fastest refactoring?